# Assigning dynamic div id with some variable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this code:

```
var someVar = ...;
<div id="myDiv@someVar"></div>
```

I tried this to render dynamic div id's but that's not ok.
How can I achive this?

Comment: Use `_` instead of `@`

Comment: What is `var someVar`? JS variable or C#?

Comment: @shaunak D read tags :)

Comment: I know. the `@` made me think of C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) does not work like that. HTML elements will not be binding to JavaScript variables natively (you can do it using frameworks like [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/)).

You have to use the JS DOM API (or instead use **jQuery**) to get the **div** element an then change its ID by code.

In this case you can to do something like this using pure **JavaScript**:

**JS**

```
var someVar = 1,
div = document.getElementById('myDiv');

div.id += someVar;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that I guess:

```js
var someVar = 'hello',
    $myDiv = $('#myDiv'),
    idDiv = $myDiv.attr('id');
$myDiv.attr('id', idDiv + someVar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```